# Binary Tree type constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying binary tree type constructor which is:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

How we prove that not all kinds of binary tree can be represented by this constructor? How we improve this definition to cover all types of binary tree? And how it works?

Comment: This `Tree` does not allow empty `Tree`, therefore, you cannot generate a `Tree` that is a list in disguise, aka `Branch 1 Leaf (Branch 2 Leaf (Branch 3 Leaf))`. That being said, I'm not really sure what you're asking about.

Comment: @Zeta you meant `Branch 1 Leaf (Branch 2 Leaf (Branch 3 Leaf Leaf))`. this is not to nitpick, of course, but for the benefit of a casual reader.

Comment: I rolled back to your first version. It is against the rules of SO to make drastic changes to the question, that invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Tree a` has labels of type `a` at every `Branch` and every `Leaf` constructor. So, for example, `Branch 'u' (Branch 'n' (Leaf 'i') (Leaf 'p')) (Leaf 'z')` looks like this:

```
    +-'u'-+
    |     |
 +-'n'-+ 'z'
 |     |
'i'   'p'
```

That excludes, say, trees with different labels at the nodes and leaves, or trees that are labelled only internally or only externally. For example, this tree has numbers at the leaves and characters at the nodes.

```
    +-'o'-+
    |     |
 +-'h'-+  9
 |     |
 7     2
```

(You can use `Tree (Either n l)` but that doesn't encode the invariant that only `n`s appear internally and only `l`s appear externally.)

Since this appears to be a homework assignment I won't tell you what a more general type of tree might look like, but I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself, how many  `a` values can your tree hold? They appear either in leaves or nodes,

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch a    (Tree a)    (Tree a)
```

so

```hs
num_values  =      1 | (      1 + num_values + num_values  )
```

It doesn't make much sense in this form, so let's write it as

```hs
numvals     =      1 : [      1 +            s          | s <- diagonalize
                                 [ [   n     +     m    | m <- numvals ] 
                                                        | n <- numvals   ] ]

diagonalize :: [[a]] -> [a]
diagonalize ((n:ns):t) = n:go [ns] t
   where
   go as (b:bs) = map head as ++ go (b:map tail as) bs
```

so that we get

> ~> take 100 numvals 
>   [1,3,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,9,9,9,9,9,11,9,9,9,11,11,11,11,9,9,11,13,11,13,11,9,9,11,13,1
>   3,13,13,11,9,9,11,13,13,15,13,13,11,11,11,11,13,13,15,15,13,13,11,11,11,13,13,13
>   ,15,15,15,13,13,13,11,11,13,15,13,15,15,15,15,13,15,13,11,11,13,15,15,15,15,15,1
>   5,15,15,15,13,11,11,13,15,15,17,15,15]

but you want *0, 2, 4, ...* to appear there as well.

*edit:* 
It is easy to fix this, with

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Now

```hs
numvals2    =    0 : [      1 +       s          | s <- diagonalize
                          [ [     n   +   m      | m <- numvals2 ] 
                                                 | n <- numvals2   ] ]
```

and

> ~> take 100 numvals2 
>   [0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,5,6,5,6,5,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,5,4,4,5
>   ,6,6,7,6,6,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,6,6,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,6,7,6,7,7,7,7,6,7,6,5
>   ,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,5,5,6,7,7,8,7,7]