# Get all possible binary trees using Prolog?

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I'm aware there are lots of questions about defining a binary tree to check whether something is a binary tree or not,but i could not find a thread that tackled this question in the "opposite direction".

> Why does your definition of binary tree not return all possible binary trees when called as "es_arbol(X)"? Explain in detail and try to implement a different definition that does return all possible binary tree structures.

Ok,so basically i'm stuck in this part of an assignment.After defining my binary-tree-validating function i noticed that when called with no arguments it just returns trees that "grow" through their right nodes,or at least that's how i interpret the output of swi-prolog.What i am not getting is,assuming my definition is correct,Prolog should be able to construct them in both ways.If not,i would like if someone could point me in the right direction to work out a more general definition of a binary tree,or maybe explain why is it that my definition is not sufficient.

This is my definition:

```
es_arbol(nil).
es_arbol(arbol(_,I,D)) :- es_arbol(I), es_arbol(D).
```

Comment: The name `arbol/3` is misleading, use `nodo/3` instead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that your predicate generates an infinite number of trees along one branch is because you have more than one recursion, and like any language, Prolog will continue making the first recursive call it finds until it returns, which in this case, never will. So you always recurse on one leg of the tree. In other words, you have at least two variables in each tree (the left and right subtrees) that have an infinite number of possibilities.

Binary trees have an infinite number of recursive possibilities along two dimensions. You need a way to order the trees using a single-dimensional metric. One such metric could be the count of nodes in the tree. If you order your trees by node count, starting with node count 0, then for each node count, there are a finite number of trees to enumerate. Here is the general way this would work:

1. `Nodes` is a valid number of nodes
2. `nil` is a valid binary tree with 0 nodes
3. `arbol(_, TL, TR)` is a valid binary tree with `N` nodes if `NL` and `NR2` add up to `N-1` and `TL` is a valid binary tree of `NL` nodes, and `TR` is a valid binary tree of `NR` nodes. Since Prolog will find all solutions from a given point before backtracking prior to that point, it will search for all of the trees with the given number of nodes first before backtracking to a new valid number of nodes.

In Prolog, it looks like this.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

es_arbol(Tree) :-
    length(_, Nodes),
    es_arbol(Tree, Nodes).
```

I'm using `length/2` to "generate" `Nodes` values of 0, 1, 2, etc. `es_arbol(Tree)` will succeed with binary trees with successive node counts starting at 0. For a given node count, `Nodes`, it will find all the solutions to `es_arbol(Tree, Nodes)` before it finally fails and backtracks to `length(_, Nodes)` again which will succeed on the next value of `Node`.

```
es_arbol(nil, 0).
es_arbol(arbol(_,TreeL,TreeR), N) :-
    N #> 0,
    NL + NR #= N - 1,
    NL #>= 0, NR #>= 0,
    es_arbol(TreeL, NL),
    es_arbol(TreeR, NR).
```

The base case is trivial. `nil` is the tree with 0 nodes. The recursive case says that `arbol(_,L,R)` is a binary tree with `N` nodes if `N > 0`, `NL` and `NR` are non-negative integers that add up to `N`, and `TL` and `TR` are binary trees with length `NL` and `NR`, respectively.

The results of running the above code are:

```
?- es_arbol(Tree).
Tree = nil ;
Tree = arbol(_G258, nil, nil) ;
Tree = arbol(_G17, nil, arbol(_G157, nil, nil)) ;
Tree = arbol(_G17, arbol(_G200, nil, nil), nil) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G154, nil, arbol(_G593, nil, nil))) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G154, arbol(_G603, nil, nil), nil)) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, arbol(_G130, nil, nil), arbol(_G191, nil, nil)) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, arbol(_G53, nil, arbol(_G193, nil, nil)), nil) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, arbol(_G53, arbol(_G236, nil, nil), nil), nil) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G100, nil, arbol(_G214, nil, arbol(_G354, nil, nil)))) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G100, nil, arbol(_G214, arbol(_G397, nil, nil), nil))) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G100, arbol(_G216, nil, nil), arbol(_G277, nil, nil))) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G100, arbol(_G139, nil, arbol(_G279, nil, nil)), nil)) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, nil, arbol(_G100, arbol(_G139, arbol(_G322, nil, nil), nil), nil)) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, arbol(_G130, nil, nil), arbol(_G191, nil, arbol(_G664, nil, nil))) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, arbol(_G130, nil, nil), arbol(_G191, arbol(_G674, nil, nil), nil)) ;
Tree = arbol(_G14, arbol(_G132, nil, arbol(_G272, nil, nil)), arbol(_G676, nil, nil)) .
...
```

---

As @false has pointed out in the comments, the use of CLP(FD) is not the most efficient way in this case of applying a enumerative constraint. An alternative, more efficient means would be to use `between/3`:

```
es_arbol(nil, 0).
es_arbol(arbol(_,TreeL,TreeR), N) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    between(0, N1, NL),
    NR is N1 - NL,
    es_arbol(TreeL, NL),
    es_arbol(TreeR, NR).
```

Comment: Is it really the case that Prolog can't express structural recursion to validate a binary tree structure, without using crutches such as numeric counters?

Comment: @Kaz, this isn't about validating a given, finite binary tree structure. This is about generating, in an enumerable way, *all* possible binary trees. Prolog is perfectly capable of validating any given, finite binary tree without resorting to using a counter.

Comment: I see; re-reading the first paragraph of the question makes it clear: going the "other way".

Comment: In some functional language we might, for instance, generate a lazy sequence, whose elements would be more complex trees from combining previously generated simpler cases.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind the code,but i can't actually get the same output as you,are you sure that's what you used when calling `es_arbol(Tree)`?

Comment: @Fgbruna It works, but `tree` in the last two lines should be `es_arbol`.

Comment: @Fgbruna I apologize, daniel is correct and I had a typing error in my post. I originally wrote and tested as `tree` then changed to `es_arbol` but didn't catch all the occurances.

Comment: Mixing constraints and labeling is a very bad idea!

Comment: @false, understood and agree. I updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: You are not exploiting constraints in any sense, even a dumb and honest `between(0, M, NL)` would be  more efficient.

Comment: @false, I agree. In this case, CLP(FD) is probably overkill. My concern in this answer was to explain the idea of constraining and enumerating. I didn't seek out the most efficient way of implementing it.

Comment: @lurker: It's not overkill. It's malaprop. It makes sense, provided you replace `>` by `#>` and remove the `label/1`. Then at least you use the functionality of clpfd which might be overkill, but not much at all.

Comment: @Kaz kind of like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680065/binary-tree-type-constructor-in-haskell/43682726#43682726)...

Answer (score 5):

Lurker has already given a very nice general solution using CLP(FD) constraints.

I would like to augment the existing answer with an alternative way to constrain the *depth* of the search. Instead of *integers*, I am using a *list* to "count" in a symbolic way.

To reason about lists in Prolog, DCG notation ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) is often very convenient, also in this case:

```
es_arbol(nil) --> [].
es_arbol(arbol(_,I,D)) --> [_], es_arbol(I), es_arbol(D).
```

Declaratively, you can think about these rules as "consuming credit" to apply.

If I query naively, then I get an *unfair* enumeration:

```
?- phrase(es_arbol(A), Ls).
A = nil,
Ls = [] ;
A = arbol(_9016, nil, nil),
Ls = [_9024] ;
A = arbol(_9016, nil, arbol(_9030, nil, nil)),
Ls = [_9024, _9038] ;
A = arbol(_9016, nil, arbol(_9030, nil, arbol(_9044, nil, nil))),
Ls = [_9024, _9038, _9052] ;
A = arbol(_9016, nil, arbol(_9030, nil, arbol(_9044, nil, arbol(_9058, nil, nil)))),
Ls = [_9024, _9038, _9052, _9066] .
```

The point is that we can easily turn this into a **fair** enumeration by restricting the *length* of the list. For example, to get all trees with exactly *two* inner node, we can use:

```
?- phrase(es_arbol(A), [_,_]).
A = arbol(_10426, nil, arbol(_10434, nil, nil)) ;
A = arbol(_10426, arbol(_10434, nil, nil), nil) ;
false.
```

Building on this, we can use **iterative deepening** to fairly enumerate all tree shapes:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(es_arbol(A), Ls).
Ls = [],
A = nil ;
Ls = [_7130],
A = arbol(_7142, nil, nil) ;
Ls = [_7130, _7136],
A = arbol(_7148, nil, arbol(_7156, nil, nil)) ;
Ls = [_7130, _7136],
A = arbol(_7148, arbol(_7156, nil, nil), nil) ;
Ls = [_7130, _7136, _7142],
A = arbol(_7154, nil, arbol(_7162, nil, arbol(_7170, nil, nil))) ;
Ls = [_7130, _7136, _7142],
A = arbol(_7154, nil, arbol(_7162, arbol(_7170, nil, nil), nil)) ;
Ls = [_7130, _7136, _7142],
A = arbol(_7154, arbol(_7162, nil, nil), arbol(_7170, nil, nil)) .
```

Thus, counting "symbolically" is sometimes a convenient alternative to using actual integers.

Comment: Nice solution! I like the elegance of constraining via the list itself rather than the counters (@Kaz).

Comment: I wonder: what could boost the popularity of s(X)-style counting? Support by `(is)/2`, perhaps?